# Flurry Analytics in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, flurry, flurry-analytics

So a bit confused here, it seems as if Flurry does not provide a `LogPageView` method like the iOS counterpart does. I was wondering how I can achieve the same logic?

Here's my iOS code that obviously works:

```
    private void FlurryLogPageView()
    {
            Flurry.Analytics.FlurryAgent.LogPageView();
    }

    private void FlurryLogEvent(string EventName)
    {
            Flurry.Analytics.FlurryAgent.LogEvent(EventName);
    }
```

We're now porting our app to Android, and upon surprise when I moved these methods to `MainActivity`, It seems that the `FlurryAgent` object does not contain a definition for `LogPageView()`. I looked at the github page provided, but the author doesn't show how to log a page view (even though the github link [here](https://github.com/mattleibow/Flurry.Analytics) explicitly says `Page View tracking` but none of the examples shows how to do that). The link to the specific example is 
[here](https://github.com/mattleibow/Flurry.Analytics/tree/master/Flurry/samples/FlurryAnalyticsAndroidSample). It only shows how to log an event, which works. I want to log a page view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard java method can be found here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/technicalquickstart/android/#track-page-views

FlurryAgent.onPageView();

There appears to be a reference to it in this file in the repo you mentioned: Portable/library/Flurry.Analytics.Portable/AnalyticsApi.cs

Comment: Well, surely, I did not have time to go through every little thing in the repo. It's a bit bizarre that the method names are different on iOS than they are on Android. Ugh. But thanks, this seems to work? As long as this is the counter-part for the iOS `LogPageView` method. Which I'm unsure if it's the same, which is why it's weird it's named different.